# Can conditions be attached to how a Geofield is populated?

Tags: 7, entities, location, javascript

Some of my nodes will be created via Feeds, which will import lat/long data, which I can store in Geofield to pass to Leaflet.

However, some of the feeds I am using do not have lat/long data, so I think I will have to create it manually by using Addressfield, with Geocoder transforming the address data and passing it to Geofield.

Is there a way to easily set a condition where, if a node doesn't already have any lat/long data, it will let me add an address to pass to Geofield?